# Failed to find byte code for javax

Tags: java, android-studio, japplet

After updating Android Studio, I'm facing these errors:

```
Failed to find bytecode for javax/swing/JApplet
```

Does someone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Is it a project specific error or is it a general Android Studio error message?

Comment: Too few information

Comment: Before the Android Studio update, the project had no problems. Now this error shows when I want to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in 3.1.  I think this issue is similar enough to be the same.
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/72811718?pli=1
I wasted so much time trying to fix it.

I eventually completely uninstalled Studio 3.1 including User files.  Then reinstalled 3.0